# Xcode raises "EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1" when Target is 7.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I use Xcode 6.3 beta4 with SDK 6.4 and Target 7.1.

Running a simple line like the following on an iOS 7.1 Simulator or Device raises an error:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: .Alert)
```

The error is:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1
```

The error does not occur when I run in an iOS 8.4 Simulator.

There seems to be a conflict caused by  different SDK versions.

**How can I prevent the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1` error running on a target with iOS version 7.x?**

Edit: Xcode shows me:

[image]

**How do I debug such an error?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UIAlertView` in **iOS7** has been replaced with `UIAlertController` in **iOS8**.

What I will suggest you is to do as follows in order to resolve compatiblity issues

```
if objc_getClass("UIAlertController") != nil {

         println("UIAlertController can be instantiated")

          //make and use a UIAlertController

     }
     else {

          println("UIAlertController can NOT be instantiated")

          //make and use a UIAlertView
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UIAlertController
```

is only valid on iOS 8.0 and above. So you must have a segmentation to use `UIAlertView` for iOS 7.

Comment: Or use just UIAlertView everywhere and don't bother with UIAlertController. That way you also make sure your code is properly tested; it's easy to have a bug in one of two versions of code.